# colorbox not working with Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, bind, colorbox

I am trying to open colorbox from dynamically loaded contents from ajax calls. On click of next it loads another block on the page and on clicking on that block, colorbox overlay should be opened.

But for the first item colorbox is opened, then after i am not able to bind colorbox with the link.

Please see, my javascript code which is used to bind colorbox is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#recommended-app-wrapper .app_download_link').each(function() {
        $(this).colorbox({
            href: $(this).attr('href'),
            iframe: false,
            onComplete: function() {
                //  Tooltip
                $('#modal a.link_tooltip').each(function() {
                    $(this).click(function() {
                        return false;
                    });
                    var content = $(this).next('.hidden').html();
                    $(this).aToolTip({   
                        tipContent: content,
                        fixed: true,
                        clickIt: false,
                        xOffset: -180,
                        yOffset: 30
                    });
                });
                //  Clear-Default
                $('#modal input.clear-default').clearDefault();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

JSP code which calls the content page is

```
<dsp:a page="/fragments/product_app_download.jsp" iclass="custom custom-blue-smapp_download_link get-app">
    <dsp:param name="id" param="element.id"/>
    Get app
</dsp:a>
```

Please see the main page, from where the ajax call is being made and it loads the block from which user can click and open the colorbox. I have taken the screenshot of the code.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Z0BVQ.png]

I think, the issue is , i am binding the colorbox on document.ready which is called only one time, then after on clicking of next it doesnt bind my next item to colorbox.

Kindly help.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to bind events to elements that haven't even been created it. I think this is what you might need.

Answer (score 0):

Think of your problem like this: On page load initially the DOM is ready, and colorbox is initilized for the selector AJAX calls a new piece of the page with some DOM element that is in the colorbox selector list, but isn't noticed because it loaded into the page after the selector was read by the javascript.

now try this, as it watches "#recommended-app-wrapper" for all, existing and new ".app_download_link":

```
$("#recommended-app-wrapper").delegate(".app_download_link", "click", function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $.colorbox({href: $(this).attr("href"),
                            transition: "fade",
                            innerHeight: '515px',
                            innerWidth: '579px',
                            overlayClose: true,
                            iframe: true,
                            opacity: 0.3},
                            onComplete: function() {
                                $('#modal a.link_tooltip').each(function(event) {
                                    if(event === "click")
                                        return false;
                                    var content = $(this).next('.hidden').html();
                                    $(this).aToolTip({   
                                       tipContent: content,
                                       fixed: true,
                                       clickIt: false,
                                       xOffset: -180,
                                       yOffset: 30
                                    });
                                });
                                //  Clear-Default
                                $('#modal input.clear-default').clearDefault();
                          });
                });
```

This way instead of waiting for letting the plugin watch for the event, watch the event with .delegate(), and execute the colorbox on the fly...

The onComplete function may not be exactly what you need, but you get the idea.